# Office.Interop how to find email using PR_SEARCH_KEY in sent Folder

Tags: outlook, interop, office-interop

I am using Outlook Object model (Interop) for my softawre.

Before I send email, I get and keep the PR_SEARCH_KEY of the email that we created.

If I want to find the email in sent folder using PR_SEARCH_KEY, how can I do that in c# using Office.Interop (not EWS or not redemption)?

I tried to find it from SentFolder.Items.Find(filter). But it does not work as the PR_SEARCH_KEY  is binary.

Thanks !

```
        public Outlook.MailItem FindEmailFromSentFolder(string emailId)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_sentFolderItems == null)
                return null;

            // find the sent mail from sent folder based on PR_Serach_Key
            var filter = string.Format("@SQL=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x300B0102\" = '{0}'",
                                   emailId);

            var item = _sentFolderItems.Find(filter);

            if (item != null && item is Outlook.MailItem)
                return item as Outlook.MailItem;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you already noticed, OOM won't let you search for any binary property - you will need Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) or Redemption (any language).

Your best bet is to set some string property on the outgoing message and then look for it in the Sent Items folder.